# Reading a nil value from dictionary key?

Tags: swift

I get a crash when I read a value from dictionary that is not there , so :

```
 let state:NSString = module["state"] as! NSString
```

is crashing,because I need the `? or !`  , so if i try to :

```
 let state:NSString = module!["state"] as! NSString
//or
 let state:NSString = module?["state"] as! NSString
```

I get an error from compiler that I have to remove the  `?/!`

So how you do that correctly ?

Comment: (Almost) every `!` is evil. Lookup "optional binding".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use optional binding.

```
if let state = module["state"] as? NSString {
  // do something with state
}

// else the value was nil
```

Or, as suggested in the comments, you can use a `guard` statement.

```
guard let state = module["state"] as? NSString else {
    // handle nil value
    return
}
```

Comment: thanks, and what if I only need to declare state and after a while I may use it? can I do {} and I will get a safe declaration ?

Comment: Actually it is called "optional binding" :)

Comment: @Curnelious you will only be able to use that variable within the `if` statement, so you should use it within. If you need it later then you may just want to check for `nil` and return or throw an error.

Comment: @MartinR yes I knew what you talking about from the first moment.Thats why I up vote you. The problem with it, is that it makes the code less clear, because sometimes you want to declare all your fields at the start of a block so you see all of them, and then you may or may not use all of them later.

Comment: you can `guard let` to use it later instead of `if let`, which looks a bit different. You provide an else block for what to do if the object isn't there (you have to return from the function inside the else block though). if it is there, then it is available for the rest of the scope the guard let is in.

Comment: @Curnelious: I assume your last comment is directed at Rohan, not at me?

Comment: @MartinR no its for you, because you where the first to comment with the same answer :)